# How to Add Image Uploader Pure JS without any XML

Tags: image-upload

I am creating a simple form in which users can add images.
I want to add the image uploader field to my custom form but the problem is, it is built with js & html. Is there a way I can add this image uploader without using xml?
[image: Image uploader]

Thank you!